# Use PDO to connect to database, execute query and fetch results in one line

Tags: php, pdo

this code is working fine:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 1;";
$stmt = $this->openDb()->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Why this code does not work and gives me the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in`

```
$result_set = $this->openDb()->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 1;")->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Because `execute()` returns a Boolean (iPhone insist Boolean is written with a capital B, so be it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$stmt->execute();doesn't return an object, it returns a boolean. http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.execute.php